# Cache Issue on HttpWebRequest vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I need away to disable chaching for my VB.NET code.  I've found some hints in C#, but nothing that I can get to work.

Right now, when i send in a request, i'm getting the previous request results.

Here's my code:

````
        Dim responseData As String = ""
        Try
            Dim cookieJar As New Net.CookieContainer()
            Dim hwrequest As Net.HttpWebRequest = Net.WebRequest.Create(URL)
            hwrequest.CookieContainer = cookieJar
            hwrequest.Accept = "*/*"
            hwrequest.AllowAutoRedirect = True
            hwrequest.UserAgent = "http_requester/0.1"
            hwrequest.Timeout = 60000
            hwrequest.Method = method

            'hwrequest.CachePolicy = CachePolicy

            If hwrequest.Method = "POST" Then
                hwrequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                Dim encoding As New Text.ASCIIEncoding() 'Use UTF8Encoding for XML requests
                Dim postByteArray() As Byte = encoding.GetBytes(POSTdata)
                hwrequest.ContentLength = postByteArray.Length
                Dim postStream As IO.Stream = hwrequest.GetRequestStream()
                postStream.Write(postByteArray, 0, postByteArray.Length)
                postStream.Close()
            End If
            Dim hwresponse As Net.HttpWebResponse = hwrequest.GetResponse()
            If hwresponse.StatusCode = Net.HttpStatusCode.OK Then
                Dim responseStream As IO.StreamReader =
                  New IO.StreamReader(hwresponse.GetResponseStream())
                responseData = responseStream.ReadToEnd()
            End If
            hwresponse.Close()
            cookieJar = Nothing
        Catch e As Exception
            responseData = "An error occurred: " & e.Message
        End Try

        Return responseData
    End Function```

Any help would be appreciated!
````

Comment: `hwrequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.CacheControl, "no-cache")`. Maybe also `hwrequest.Headers.Add("DNT", "1")` :). If you're trying to perform a login of sort and you get the same data back, then you're receiving the login page over and over, because the login failed.

Comment: thanks :) - I added: ':
            hwrequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.CacheControl, "no-cache")
            hwrequest.Headers.Add("DNT", "1")'

I'm not doing a login - this is getting orders from WooCommerce that are processed.  Thanks for your help!